# Xdebug not stopping on CLI script breakpoints in PHPstorm on vagrant

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

Not sure what I did to break it, but Xdebug is no longer working on any projects on my vagrant when running CLI scripts such as Laravel commands. Still works on web requests.

Here is the contents of `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 10
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.collect_return = 1
xdebug.collect_params = 10
xdebug.show_mem_delta = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/home/vagrant/Projects/xdebug_profiler"
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "/home/vagrant/Projects/xdebug_traces"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.trace_enable = 1
xdebug.cli_color = 1
```

PHPStorm is configured for port 9001 on Xdebug in project preferences. (HHVM conflicts on port 9000 even tho I'm not running HHVM)

[image]

I also have the ide key set to "PHPSTORM" for the "PHP Remote Debug" configuration for my vagrant dev host.

[image]

Absolute paths are also set for that server in PHPStorm.

[image]

Clicking the listener and then the debug icon opens the debug tab, but it never stops on any breakpoints.

[image]

CLI output of `phpinfo()` gives me this info on Xdebug:

```
xdebug support => enabled
Version => 2.3.2
IDE Key => PHPSTORM

Supported protocols => Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol => $Revision: 1.145 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 1 => 1
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 10 => 10
xdebug.collect_return => On => On
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => PHPSTORM => PHPSTORM
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => On => On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => On => On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /home/vagrant/Projects/xdebug_profiler => /home/vagrant/Projects/xdebug_profiler
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart => On => On
xdebug.remote_connect_back => On => On
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => localhost => localhost
xdebug.remote_log => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9001 => 9001
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => On => On
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => On => On
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /home/vagrant/Projects/xdebug_traces => /home/vagrant/Projects/xdebug_traces
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => -1 => -1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 10 => 10
```

Here is the `xdebug.remote_log` output:

```
Log opened at 2015-11-18 03:34:23
I: Checking remote connect back address.
W: Remote address not found, connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9001. :-|
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2015-11-18 03:34:23
```

This is Ubuntu 14 running on a slightly modded Homestead vagrant box under PHPStorm 9.0.2 on Mac OS 10.11.1.

Anything look out of sorts here to explain the malfunction?

Comment: **1)** Please provide xdebug logs (`xdebug.remote_log`). So far it most likely works ... but connects to local 9001 port instead of remote (your PC). **2)** Since you want to debug a script in a browser (based on your Run/Debug Configuration in PhpStorm; am I right?) then you should capture `phpinfo()` output via browser as well. If you intend to debug actual CLI script (launched and executed in CLI environment -- e.g. in Terminal) then this config is inoimplete.

Comment: So -- xdebug log first. After that we can look at 3) If those ports are mapped/open in actual Vagrant (can make outgoing connection); 4) maybe it's your local firewall.

Comment: The web Xdebug connection already works. It's only the CLI connection that is broken. Updated question with `remote_log` value.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this when I realized that another vagrant box with `xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.56.1` in the xdebug config was connecting over CLI. The VagrantFile had the value `ip: "192.168.56.101"`.

That lead me to discover a [post on walkah.net](http://walkah.net/blog/debugging-php-with-vagrant/) that used the same sort of IP convention.

With that in mind, I took the `ip: "192.168.10.10"` value from the VagrantFile on my vagrant box that Xdebug can't connect to from CLI, and changed it for use in the setting `xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.10.1`.

I can now debug breakpoints from that vagrant box using PHPStorm again. :)